# Print and write values in a file greater and lesser than 10 and make a plot of it by using Python

Tags: python

I have a enormous data in (.csv) format which consists of various columns from that of my interest is column 3 and 7. I want to print both columns

```
 Sample Data: {Only Col 3 and 7 are displayed}
    Names   Numbers
    John    12
    Kim      5
    Alex    16
    mike    2
    giki    8
    David   18
```

Desired Output #values greater than 10:

```
John    12
Alex    16
David   18
```

Desired Output #values lesser than 10:

```
Kim      5
mike     2
giki     8
```

Comment: What did you try so far? What problems did you run into?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your "sample data" does not have a column 3 or 7 so it is not actually sample data for your problem. Please change either the problem or the sample data to match. Also, the "plot of both the files" is not clear. Since the names are different in the two files, just how should the plot be done? Please show us the desired plot from your sample data. Finally, please explain the attempts you have made so far on this problem, preferably with sample code. Read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rhea

I'm not sure I understand what are trying to accomplish there, therefore I'll try to help you going through some basic stuff:

a) Do you already have your data on a DataFrame format? Or it is in some form of tabular data such as a csv or Excel file?

Dataframe = Two-dimensional size-mutable, potentially heterogeneous tabular data structure with labeled axes (rows and columns).

Anyways you will have to import pandas to read or manipulate this file. Then you can transform it into a DataFrame using one of Pandas reading functions, such as `pandas.read_csv` or `pandas.read_excel`.

```
import pandas as pd
# if your data is in a dictionary
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
# csv
df = pd.read_csv('file name and path')
```

b) Then you can slice through it using pandas, and create new DataFrames

```
output1 = df.loc[df['Numbers'] > 10]
output2 = df.loc[df['Numbers'] < 10]
```

c) The most basic way to plot is using the pandas method `plot` on your new DataFrame (you can get a lot fancier than that using matplotlib or seaborn). Although you should probably think about what kind of information you want to visualize, which is not clear to me.

```
out1.plot()
#histogram
out2.hist()
```

d) You can save your new dataframes using pandas as well. Here is an example of a CSV file

```
df.to_csv(path_or_buf=None, sep=', ', na_rep='', float_format=None, columns=None, header=True, index=True, index_label=None)
```

I hope I could shed some light into your doubts ;) .